# Give an optimal flexbox width but allow shrink when parent has no more room

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a wrapper div with flexbox on it, containing two other divs:

[image]

The right hand div has 3 other divs in it, one is a search bar

[image]

Is there a way I can use flexbox to say fill all the space available, unless the parent is being forced to shrink?

[image]

**This is my CSS**

```
.header-nav {
  background: $storm;
  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .logo {
    display: block;
  }
  a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .is-search {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background:yellow;
  }
}

.header-nav-profile {
  display: flex;
}

.block-menu,
.inline-menu {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
}

.inline-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  a {
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 10px;
  }
}

.block-menu {
  border-left: 1px solid $grey;
  border-right: 1px solid $grey;
  a {
    display:block;
    padding: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  li + li a,
  .is-search {
    border-left: 1px solid $grey;
  }
  .is-search {
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    // flex-basis: 280px;
  }
}
```

**And HTML**

```
<div class="header-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-nav-profile">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="Logo" class="logo">
      </a>
      <ul class="inline-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Name</a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-icon">
          <a href="#">Add bookmark</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">View bookmark</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="block-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Period</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Filters</a>
      </li>
      <li class="is-search">
        <div class="search">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <span class="submit"></span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a link to a demo if you want to try it out:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/dmZxRv?editors=1100

I'd like the search bar to have a good length (longer than the other two items in its div) then as the width gets smaller only then does it start shrinking.

Comment: This? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRpBGz?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max-width: pixel amount;` and `max-height: pixel amount;`.

It that doesn’t work, it’s possible with `@media` tags.

```
.selector {
  width: normal width;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .selector {
    width: percent amount; /* Width when window is thinner than 800px */
  }
}
```

Comment: In the pen I have made a `.ruler` div with the ideal length I'd like it. The issue is, its not long enough to start with, but I'd also like it to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your block menu class like this:

```
.block-menu {
        border-left: 1px solid grey;
        border-right: 1px solid grey;
    flex-grow:1;
    justify-content:flex-end
}
```

Basically you can use `flex-grow` to take up the available space and then `justify-content:flex-end` to move them to the right (end of) the container.

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/jchaplin2/pen/EEoYmw?editors=1100)